# why DataContractSerializer is faster that xmlSerializer?

Tags: .net, serialization, datacontractserializer

Performance wise, why and how Datacontract serializer is better than xmlserializer ?

Comment: Because Microsoft put a lot of effort into making it faster .... the DataContractSerializer has some limitation, e.g. it doesn't support attributes on XML nodes, because supporting those would have made it quite a bit slower.

Comment: @marc_s: i know microsoft put a lot effort into it, but i want to know what they did to make it fast? read question care fully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From:
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and also
[link2](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/)

> Is about 10% faster than XmlSerializer
>   to serialize the data because since
>   you don’t have full control over how
>   it is serialize, there is a lot that
>   can be done to optimize the
>   serialization/deserialization process.

The main differences I have noticed:

- The output is not formatted
- The created object does always have it's constructor called, which implies that only one object is created and then the memory is copied for all subsequent objects
- I suspect there are also other improvements relating to the way it casts the types when deserializing the data.